# Need guidance and tips on oxmlelement

Tags: python-docx

I am currently manipulating a word document using Python-docx and I would like to standardize every table/figure caption to either match with their corresponding heading or just increment them based on user choice.

I am currently stuck with the field code as I need to also update the field automatically. Below is a sample field code which I have from the document and would like to achieve

```
Table { STYLEREF 1 \s }-{ SEQ Table \* ARABIC \s 1} Random Heading Name
```

[I have referenced from this github link](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/359)

```
paragraph = document.add_paragraph('Table ', style='Caption')
run = run = paragraph.add_run()
r = run._r
fldChar = OxmlElement('w:fldChar')
fldChar.set(qn('w:fldCharType'), 'begin')
r.append(fldChar)
instrText = OxmlElement('w:instrText')
instrText.text = ' STYLEREF 1 \s '
r.append(instrText)
fldChar = OxmlElement('w:fldChar')
fldChar.set(qn('w:fldCharType'), 'end')
r.append(fldChar)

instrText = OxmlElement('w:instrText')
instrText.set(qn('xml:space'), 'preserve')  # sets attribute on element
r.append(instrText)

fldChar = OxmlElement('w:fldChar')
fldChar.set(qn('w:fldCharType'), 'begin')
r.append(fldChar)
instrText = OxmlElement('w:instrText')
instrText.text = ' SEQ Table \* ARABIC \s 1'
r.append(instrText)
fldChar = OxmlElement('w:fldChar')
fldChar.set(qn('w:fldCharType'), 'end')
r.append(fldChar)
```

I have tried using preserver and separate but they can't seem to get "-" which I need sitting in between the 2 field code.

So right now, my end product is:

```
Table { STYLEREF 1 \s }{ SEQ Table \* ARABIC \s 1} Random Heading Name
```